# JavaScript types

Tags: javascript, ecma262

As per http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf,
JavaScript has 6 types: `undefined`, `null`, `boolean`, `string`, `number` and `object`.

```
var und;
console.log(typeof und); // <-- undefined

var n = null;
console.log(typeof n); // <--- **object**!

var b = true;
console.log(typeof b); // <-- boolean

var str = "myString"
console.log(typeof str); // <-- string

var int = 10;
console.log(typeof int); // <-- number

var obj = {}
console.log(typeof obj); // <-- object
```

**Question 1:**

Why is null of type `object` instead of `null`?

**Question 2:**

What about functions?

```
var f = function() {};
console.log(typeof f); // <-- function
```

Variable `f` has type of `function`. Why isn't it specified in the specification
as a separate type?

Thanks,

Comment: +1 for digging in the spec, looking for holistic enlightenment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

About `typeof null == 'object'`, this is a mistake that comes since the early days, and unfortunately this mistake will stay with us for a long time, it was [**too late**](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=proposals:typeof) to be fixed in the *ECMAScript 5th* Edition Specification.

About the **functions**, they are just objects, but they have an special internal property named [`[[Call]]`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2.1) which is used internally when a function is invoked.

The [`typeof`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.4.3) operator distinguish between plain objects and functions just by checking if the object has this internal property.

Answer (score 5):

It's because `typeof` is defined to return "object" if the input is `null`, and return "function" if the input is callable. (See 11.4.3 The `typeof` Operator.)

I don't know why the standard is defined like this ([and Crockford said it's wrong](http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html)). Maybe backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to Question 1:**

A property, when it has no definition, is undefined. The reason null is an Object is so that a property can exist with no value yet still have a definition.

Comment: Actually I think that's kind of misleading.  There is a difference between undefined and undeclared.  For instance, `var x` will put a property named `x` in the current scope, but its value will be `undefined`.  Before this happens, `x` itself is undefined, and trying to use it will result in a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: Also, `null` is *not* an Object, it is a *primitive value*, sadly the `typeof` operator is just wrong...

Answer (score 0):

`typeof null === "object"` because the spec says so, but this is a mistake from the very first version of JavaScript.  (as KennyTM says above).

`typeof f === "function"` because, without a `try`/`catch`, there is no other reliable, foolproof way to determine if something is callable.  Using `f.constructor === Function` *might* work, but I think it's not guaranteed to be so.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, note that the current best-practice way to check type information is something like this:

```
var typeInfo = Object.prototype.toString.call(yourObject);
```

That gives you a string that looks like "[object Something]", where "Something" is a type name.

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined)` gives me `[object Window]` in Firefox o_O.

Comment: KennyTM: That's because when `null` or `undefined` are used as the first argument of `call` or `apply`, the context (the `this` keyword) inside the invoked function will be set to the global object.

Comment: Right - if using that technique you'd probably do an explicit === test for undefined first

Answer (score 0):

null is a special value- it is not false, it is not 0, or the empty string or NaN or undefined.

null is what you get when you look for an object that is not there-
not an undefined property of an object, but the thing itself.

a paragraph with one textNode will return null for the nodes nextSibling, 
a regexp that does'n match returns null instead of the array
and so on.

maybe it should have its own type, 
but then it starts to be something,
a something with a type, instead of the absence of an object.

Answer (score 0):

There is also Array.prototype as well.

- Object.prototype
- Array.prototype
- Function.prototype
- Number.prototype
- String.prototype
- Boolean.prototype

[Crockford](http://post.oreilly.com/form/oreilly/viewhtml/9z1z5ns0kccq4lb6v37echce62h8rlcv3ggnatvr7bg?utm_content=em-orm-ug-dd-f2v&utm_campaign=UG&utm_source=iPost&utm_medium=email&imm_mid=06e7bd&cmp=em-orm-ug-dd-f2v) says not to use:

- new Number()
- new String()
- new Boolean()